# plot graphviz to map

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, graphviz

I have a set of latitude and longitude values for given nodes. I have projected these latitude,longitude to x,y and fed them to .dot code and generated graph using graphviz 2.29.
The command is:

```
neato -Tpng -o sample.png sourcegv.dot
```

The output graph is:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/brpnt

The source code for generation this graph is:

```
digraph {
rankdir=LR;


subgraph cluster1{

label="cluster 1" 

node[style=filled,color=cornflowerblue, fontcolor=white]
edge[arrowhead=vee,  color=maroon] 

n0[label="192.168.8.9" pos = "69.0,15.5!"];
n1[label="192.168.8.8" pos = "70.25,12.75!"];
n2[label="192.168.8.6" pos = "78.0,9.5!"];

 n0 -> n1 ;
 n1 -> n2 ;
 n0 -> n2 ;
 n2 -> n1 ;
 n2 -> n0 ;
 n1 -> n0 ;
};

subgraph cluster2{

label="cluster 2" 

node[style=filled,color=cornflowerblue, fontcolor=white]
edge[arrowhead=vee,  color=maroon] 

m0[label="192.168.8.9" pos = "70.5,18.25!"];
m1[label="192.168.8.8" pos = "75.25,17.75!"];
m2[label="192.168.8.6" pos = "70.25,16.5!"];

 m0 -> m1;
 m1 -> m2 ;
 m0 -> m2 ;
 m2 -> m1 ;
 m2 -> m0 ;
 m1 -> m0 ;
};

}
```

I am searching for some ways, so that I can plot the graph in **real map**( like google earth or googlemap) so that the nodes can be fixed to the position given by the latitude and longitude.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong tool for the job. Graphviz is for graphs, not maps. You should checkout Matplotlib's [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) for an easy to use tool. It's Python, but you only have to know a tiny bit to use it. [Here's a good tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/plotting-geographical-data-using-basemap) too.

Comment: Also, something that might be easier is to just generate a Google Map using the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/). You just pass the label, latitude, and longitude, and you can create a marker easily.

Comment: @jmdeldin you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphviz is, unfortunately, the wrong tool for the job. It's for graphs, not maps. However, there are a few very good options:

1. Matplotlib's [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/): It's in Python, but you only have to know a tiny bit to use it. Matplotlib has tons of [examples](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), but it's pretty easy to find good tutorials. Here's a [good tutorial on the Basemap package](http://www.packtpub.com/article/plotting-geographical-data-using-basemap) too.
2. [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/): You just pass the label, latitude, and longitude to the API to plot a marker. You can generate [static images](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) or interactive maps too.
3. For completeness, you may want to check out a JavaScript library like [Cartographer.js](http://cartographer.visualmotive.com/) or [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/)

Sadly, none of these are as simple as the `dot` language, but Matplotlib comes pretty close.